# Android parse json get org.json.JSONException error

Tags: android, json, android-json

```
    String jsonStr = HelperInputStream.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
    if (jsonStr == null) {
        return;
    }
    String code,message = "";
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        Log.e("code:" , object.getString("subject"));
```

`jsonStr` result is:

`[{"code":"1","subject":"you have new message"}]`

unfortunately i get this error is `catch`:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"subject":"you have new message","code":"1"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

whats my code problem. in server i have only this code:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(array(
        array(
            'code'=>'1',
            'subject'=>"you have new message",
        )
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subject` key is in JSONObject which is inside JSONArray so get JSONArray from `jsonStr` string:

```
JSONArray arrJSON = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
JSONObject object=arrJSON.getJSONObject(0);
Log.e("code:" , object.getString("subject"));
```

Comment: thanks sir, why i can not use `switch` for `String code    = i.getStringExtra("code");` i like to using `switch` instead of `if`, i get this error: `Error:(145, 24) java: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)`